# Get most frequent value in a list with lists inside (python)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the most frequent value for each list inside of maxlist. However everytime I try these functions or tutorials I either end up showing the full list or it says 'object list is not callable'.

In the end my goal is to get the most frequent value (here it is '2') from every list inside of maxlist and put the new values inside a new list called 'results'

[image: maxlist]

Comment: Have a look at [Counter](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. Replace with your inputs

```py
from collections import Counter 

l = [[0,0,1],
     [1,1,2]]

list_ = []
for ele in l:
    list_.append(Counter(ele).most_common(1)[0][0])
print(list_)
```

output:

```py
[0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use numpy

```
import numpy as np
l = [[0,0,1],
     [1,1,2]]

nums, counts = np.unique(l, return_counts = True)
print(nums[np.argwhere(counts == counts.max())])
```